# How to get rid of - "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?

Tags: java, image-processing

How to get rid of - "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at beproject.Decode.<init>(Decode.java:24)
    at beproject.Encode.calDeco(Encode.java:106)
    at beproject.Aloco.mainMethod(Aloco.java:138)
    at beproject.UI.compressActionPerformed(UI.java:212)
    at beproject.UI.access$100(UI.java:24)
    at beproject.UI$2.actionPerformed(UI.java:77)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
```

Comment: Not to allocate too much memory in `beproject.Decode`?  Without code on what `Decode` and `Encode` do, you will not get much help...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a memory leak, using for example -Xmx256m as an argument when starting the JVM will increase the heap memory available to your program, if it just needs more to run.

Comment: hey thanks alot but how to increase the size in netbeans if i am directly running the project in netbeans only??